# How can I have ld add symbols pointing to a section?

Tags: c, gcc, embedded, ld, avr-gcc

I have some variables in my C code that are declared with `__attribute__((section(".data.mystuff")))`. I would like to define two symbols, `mystuff_start` and `mystuff_size` that have the position and size of the section. It looks like `ld`'s `LOADADDR` and `SIZEOF` will do what I want, but I don't want to write the whole linker script. I can't figure out how to use `INSERT AFTER` to do what I want either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to put them into a section that has a valid C identifier as it's name.  For example, use:

```
__attribute__((section("mystuff")))
```

and you'll have automagic variables `__start_mystuff` and `__stop_mystuff` which will give you the start and end addresses of the section which you can declare in your source as extern variables.

EDIT: this is completely GCC specific!

Comment: Most C compilers have similar variables or functions. In Green Hills have __ghsbeginXXX, __ghsendXXX, and __ghssizeXXX.

Comment: And IAR have two functions returning pointers __segment_begin(segment)
and __segment_end(segment)

Comment: The linker doesn't like it, though:

/opt/local/lib/gcc/avr/4.7.2/../../../../avr/bin/ld: section cli_cmdtable loaded at [000000000000175a,0000000000001771] overlaps section .data loaded at [000000000000175a,000000000000193b]

Comment: @ Derecho: You should update your linker file to make space for the stuff that go into mystuff.

Comment: @Gerhard But can I do that by augmenting the default linker script? I'd prefer that to having to copy the whole thing from GCC into my project to modify it.

Comment: @ Derecho You can only have one linker script. You will need to take the default and modify it. You can modify it when building using arguments to gcc. -Xlinker -defsym=SYMBOL_RAM_START=$(VALUE_TO_OVERRIDE)

Comment: @Gerhard As I understand it, you can have multiple linker scripts. There's the main one (either default or specified with `-T`), and there are any you specify as though they were object files. And if you specify with `-T` one that has `INSERT AFTER` or `INSERT BEFORE`, it *augments* rather than replaces the default one. Is this incorrect? The point is, I can't define the start of my section manually, because I don't know how big the `.data` section before it is. I also need my section to go in the same output section as `.data`.